# Reference request: basics about modular curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, riemann-surfaces

Where can I find a reference (with carefully written proofs) for basic facts about modular curves? Namely:

- Congruence subgroups
- The open modular curve $Y_\Gamma$ admits the structure of a Riemann surface (dealing with the issue of orbifold points)
- The curve $Y_\Gamma$ admits a completion at the cusps to give a closed Riemann surface $X_\Gamma$

Ideally, with no mention of the word "stack". I'm mostly interested in understanding the complex analytic side of the story.

Comment: Perhaps Shimura, *Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions*?

Comment: Another reference (maybe more accessible, depending on your taste) is Diamond-Shurman, A first course in modular forms.

Comment: Modular Forms by Miyake is booked that I learned from and liked especially for the topics you mentioned. It’s in the same style as Shimura but a much easier read in my opinion. It doesn’t get to as many advanced topics as Shimura but treats the ones you mentioned well.

Comment: Drew Sutherland taught an undergraduate course last year at MIT. He's written up great lecture notes at https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2017/lectures.html which contain what you're looking for. Diamond-Shurman and Miyake are also nice reads.